# How to get all types inheriting class at compile time?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to write networking code that automatically serializes and deserializes a packet into a `NetworkMessage`.

Here's the code for `NetworkMessage`

```
public abstract class NetworkMessage : ISerializable
{
    public readonly NetworkClient Client;

    protected NetworkMessage(NetworkClient client)
    {
        this.Client = client;
    }

    public abstract void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
}
```

And here's the code for a sample `NetworkMessageText`

```
public class NetworkMessageText : NetworkMessage
{
    public static readonly Byte Id = 0x01;

    public readonly String Message;

    public NetworkMessageText(NetworkClient client, String message)
        : base(client)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("message", this.Message, typeof(String));
    }
}
```

Now, to deserialize that, I'll need to look up the Id in a Dictionary<Byte,Type>, where I have registered the different Ids at code-time.

This is the `NetworkMessagesIds` class which does that for me

```
public static class NetworkMessageIds
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Byte> TypeIdDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Byte>();
    private static readonly Dictionary<Byte, Type> IdTypeDictionary = new Dictionary<Byte, Type>(); 

    static NetworkMessageIds()
    {
        TypeIdDictionary.Add(typeof(NetworkMessageText), NetworkMessageText.Id);
        IdTypeDictionary.Add(NetworkMessageText.Id, typeof(NetworkMessageText));
    }

    public static Byte IdFromType(Type type)
    {
        return TypeIdDictionary[type];
    }

    public static Type TypeFromId(Byte id)
    {
        return IdTypeDictionary[id];
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to automatically generate the Id byte for each class which inherits `NetworkMessage` at compile time. I could do it at runtime using Reflection, but then I don't know if I can trust the Ids to be the same every time for every machine, and using Reflection does seem a bit excessive for something like this.

Alternatively, suggestions on different approaches with the same result is welcome, what I basically need is an easily extendible solution, where the "end-user" only needs to inherit `NetworkMessage` for their code to work with the networking solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing it at compile time you could do it on application load and cache what you find or not (I tend not to in order to allow runtime extensibility). Here is some (untested) code that will find all of the children of 'NetworkMessage':

```
var knownMessageTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList().ForEach(a => a.GetTypes().ToList().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(NetworkMessage)));
```

Then if you create an attribute for use on any children of NetworkMessage to identify the message ID byte, you can dynamically discover which types you can use to deserialize messages.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class NetworkMessageAttribute : Attribute
{
    public byte MessageID { get; set }
}
```

Then you can create a network message type as follows:

```
[NetworkMessage(MessageID = 0x01)]
public class ExampleNetworkMessage : NetworkMessage
```

I've used this general design concept with success on several different projects.

---

EDIT: If you really want to achieve your goal as you have it designed above it can be achieved with a similar approach to the above code. Just put it into a console application which will generate a message definition list file to be read by your application and set it up as a post build activity in your project.

Comment: Can I be 100% sure that the Ids assigned will be the same every time it's run and on every machine/hardware setup possible? It wouldn't be good if a message it deserialized wrong on a client.

Comment: If the attribute used on the NetworkMessage implementation specifies which message id should be used to identify the implementation then yes. I'll update my answer with a sample attribute and implementation.

Comment: @MindWorX: The problem with generating the message ID's at compile time is that it doesn't really solve the problem you are trying to solve. When you rebuild your code, there is no guarantee that the message ID's won't change (not as bad as at each run though) unless you build in management. The only way that I've found to mitigate the issue consistently is to have fixed IDs for each class identified by the attribute.

Comment: I really like this approach, and it also gives me a peek at how Attributes are designed and implemented. However, I don't mind the IDs changing from build to build. The server and client networking will always be built at the same time. But I guess doing it like this is a lot safer than relying on compile-time ID generation. And this is still easily managed by the end-user of the networking library.

Comment: @MindWorX: The biggest issue I have with using compile time generation of message ID's is that it removes the possibility for backward compatibility (which for me has always been an issue). I'm glad you like the approach. If you need further help building out the design described here let us know. I'm sure there are others that can provide assistance where needed. If this answer helped your cause than please mark it as your answer or at least up vote it to show your appreciation.

Comment: Alright, I implemented the solution using custom attributes, and so far it's working fine. I've marked this the answer, as it solved my problem by providing a usable alternative.

Comment: @MindWorX: Please let us know if you encounter any further issues.